# How to make a project for compilation videos?

Tags: premiere, pro

I am trying to create a project that will automatically convert videos to a compilation. Although not literally, but kinda.

I want to create project that will hold effects, motion data in specified duration, then import videos into them, is it possible to apply motion and effects to sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Premiere, you can create a master sequence consisting of nested sequences and apply motion and effects to those nested sequences within the master sequence.

And swap footage within those nested sequences as desired.

Comment: Thanks but I am fairly new to Premiere actually, can you guide me with a video if possible, please? Thanks!

Comment: See http://4.sendvid.com/bhg98x58.mp4  - it's a crude demo. First, I populate two sequences with a clip each. Import those sequences in another sequence. Apply motion. And then swap out the clips in the nested sequences.

Comment: You're great! This is absolutely I was looking for! Thanks a lot :)